# Visual Studio CS0161: Fonts and Colors

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, colors, ide, visual-studio-2017

I would like to change the display color for the error message: `CS0161: Not all code paths return a value`.

The red underline disturbs me.

[image]

Under **Fonts and Colors** I can't find the corresponding entry.

I use *Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.4.1)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the color you're looking for is called Syntax Error:

[image: Syntax Error color settings]

Comment: Yeah, that changes the color. Too bad there is no extra entry for this, thanks for the answer!